# Desactivar App como administrador Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy queriendo desactivar mi aplicaciòn como adinistrador desde Java lanzando un Intent, ya que con el siguien codigo lanza el Intent para Activarla

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, angelDevicePolicyAdmin);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,  "Administración del dispositivo");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Me gustaría lanzar esta mistad actividad pero para desactivarla cuando este activada, lo inverso de lo anterior 
Pero no veo algo que realice no contrario a esto

```
DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN
```

Comment: Tengo curiosidad para que sirve activar una app ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN

Comment: @Webserveis necesito bloquear el dispositivo, cuando se vaya a realizar una acción indebida, que el usuario previamente configuro. Es una App para seguridad

Answer (score 2):

Pon el nombre de la clase de tu device admin en donde esta`DeviceAdminSample`
esto te sirve para desactivarlo:

```
public void disableDeviceAdmin() {
    ComponentName devAdminReceiver = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminSample.class);
    DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    dpm.removeActiveAdmin(devAdminReceiver);
}
```

Para comprobar si esta activo prueba:

```
public boolean isDeviceAdminEnabled() {
    DevicePolicyManager mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    ComponentName mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminSample.class);
    return (mDPM != null && mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName));
}
```